# How do you interpret: option to break after 12 months with at least 2 months’ notice

Tags: rental-property

"option to break after 12 months with at least 2 months’ notice"

In my opinion, the sentence above can be interpreted as follows:

1) the agreement can be broken at least 12 months after inception date. In our case, the agreement starts June 1st 2019 and hence the agreement cannot be broken before May 31st 2020.

2) Would we wanna break the agreement, we need to give a 2 months notice before ending the agreement. Example: if we wanna leave Sept 1st 2020, we need to inform you/the landlord latest June 31st 2020.

Both conditions 1 and 2 have to be fulfilled. The two conditions are inclusive.

Comment: What jurisdiction? That's not how I read it. You can give notice before the start of month 11 (before April 1) that you plan to end/break the lease at the end of month 12 (May 31).

Comment: Jurisdiction: United kingdom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. And yes, both conditions need to be met.

Other terms in the lease might clarify that the last month's rent will not be prorated even if the notice is such that the unit is vacated prior to the end of a calendar month.

Comment: @DJohnM No. That is just a one-month (or 30-day) notice, not a two-month notice. For termination to be effective on June 2, 2020, the notice would have to be given no later than April 2, 2020. But it is definitely possible for termination to be effective on June 2, 2020, because the twelve-month clause refers to *termination* itself, not to the *notice* thereof.